# How to use Ajax on Laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I made a JavaScript code to process my request search request using Ajax. So thus, my code is defined as the following:

```
if(document.getElementById('category')){
    document.getElementById('category').addEventListener('click', () => {
        var query = document.getElementById('category').value;
        if(query !== ''){
            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpRequest.open('GET', "http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/fetch");
            httpRequest.send();
            console.log(httpRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

where my `category` is from my form:

```html
<div class="col s12 m8 l8">
    <input type="text" name="category" value="{{old('category') ?? $book->category ? $book->category->name : ''}}" class="input-field validate" id="category">
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="{{ $book->category ? $book->category->id : ''}}">
</div>
```

and my get request refers to my function:

```
public function fetch(Request $request){
    dd("You hit me: ".$request);
    $category = Category::where('name', 'like', $request['category'])->first();
    return response()->json($category);
}
```

but back to my JavaScript, **Why my get request is not hitting my fetch function? while doing it manually on browser it gives me the result** and also my console is giving me this kind of result:

```
response: "<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc)"
```

like the image below.
[image: Ajax Request]

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

To provide a little bit of context, Laravel is built in part off of Symfony, another PHP framework, and shares a lot of packages. One such package is called `var-dumper`, and it's what enables the `dd` helper function in Laravel.

Take a look at this sample, taken straight from the `dd` helper package:

```
//...
<script>
Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) {
//...
```

[Source](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper/blob/a0bdec5a86cef43b0e67b8ec1203f6481d5b7c10/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php#L163-L164)

Look familiar? If you viewed the source of the page that you're saying works manually in the browser, you'll see the exact same code. Turns out what you're seeing in your AJAX request is correct after all -- it's just raw HTML content that hasn't been transformed by the browser.

---

If you want to output non-dd content (as in, not marked up with script tags and other fancy-ness), try using PHP's built-in [`die('Your message')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) method (only for debugging!) or just stick to Laravel's built in `response()->json` methods.

Hope that helps!